# Is there any way to only move one step up and down

Tags: c#

I'm developing a kind of remote controller car.
I'm using a window CE device and Compact Framework 2.0 C#.

When Remote controller adjust the speed of car,
I'm using a sequential way like stairs.
However, It is sometimes going up and down 2 steps, 4 steps.
I would like to make only one step up and down from now step.

For example, now step is 4 then I just go to 3 or 5 not 8 or 1.

```
 // Dealing with GPIO Input signal (detect push button)
 private void smartGPIO1_EvtPortADatasChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iPortDatas;
    SmartX.PORTDataEvtArgs PortDatas;

    PortDatas = (SmartX.PORTDataEvtArgs)e;

    iPortDatas = PortDatas.iPortDatas;

   if (!test_start_Flag)
   {


    // User push the down button
    if ((iPortDatas & 0x08) == 0x00)
    {
        
        motor_step = (motor_step <= -2) ? -2 : motor_step -= 1;
        motor_handler(motor_step);
        
        

    }

    // User push the up button
    if ((iPortDatas & 0x05) == 0x01)
    {
        
        motor_step = (motor_step >= 12) ? 12 : motor_step += 1;
        motor_handler(motor_step);
            
    }
  }      
}

// When button is pushed, send a command to car depends on the step
    public int motor_handler(int step)
    {
        switch (step)
        {
            case 0:
                // send command
                
                break;
            case 1:
             
                
                break;
            case 2:
             
                
                break;
            case 3:
             
                
                break;
            case 4:
           
                
                break;
            case 5:
         
                break;
            case 6:
              
                
                break;
            case 7:
                
                
                break;
            case 8:
                
                
                break;
            case 9:
              
                
                break;
            case 10:
               
                
                break;
            case 11:
              
                
                break;
            case 12:
             
                
                break;
           
                
                break;
            case -1:
                
                
                break;
            case -2:
             
           
                break;
        }
        return step;
    }
```

Comment: Your code only ever increments or decrements the motor_step by 1 so if you're finding that the variable value jumps up by 2 etc then the code must have run twice in quick succession

Comment: Define the variable 'motor_step' INSIDE the function so that it no longer global. That way, even when pressed in quick succession it will always increment by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is for sure looped through on every update. Meaning that the single push of up or down button gets registered tens of times every second, so it seems like it goes more than one step at a time. You need to somehow register only new button presses.

```
//define something like this to the class level
Bool downIsPressed;
Bool upIsPressed;

//and then check and modify those values
if ((iPortDatas & 0x08) == 0x00 && downIsPressed == false)
    {
        motor_step = (motor_step <= -2) ? -2 : motor_step -= 1;
        motor_handler(motor_step);
        downIsPressed = true;
    }
else 
{
  downIsPressed = false;
}
```

That should only register the button once and enable it once the button is released. There might be some cleaner and nicer looking way too, but hope that is of some help :)

Comment: It is very simple solution. I've never thought that!. Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Is it Recursive?

```
motor_handler(motor_step);
```

Calls  `private void smartGPIO1_EvtPortADatasChange(object sender, EventArgs e)`

That's why each button push you get two steps.

The solution is a Private Boolean, typically I name `IsRecursive`:

```
class RacingCar {
    private bool IsRecursive = false;
    private void smartGPIO1_EvtPortADatasChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsRecursive) return;
        IsRecursive = true;
    
    ....
    
        IsRecursive = false;              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code only ever increments or decrements the motor_step by 1 so if you're finding that the variable value jumps up by 2 etc then the code must have run twice in quick succession.

You have to find a way to "debounce" two events arriving at the same time. For example, when you step, record the current time. If the next event occurs less than one second since the previous event, ignore the event

```
//declare var and set to min value 
private DateTime last_event_time = DateTime.MinValue;

private void smartGPIO1_EvtPortADatasChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //debounce
    if((DateTime.Now - last_event_time).TotalSeconds < 1)
      return;
   last_event_time = DateTime.Now;

    int iPortDatas;
    SmartX.PORTDataEvtArgs PortDatas;
```

Note: I've no idea if using DateTime will work on your platform, please take this code as pseudocode to demonstrate the *concept*

Debouncing like this will rely on the fact that the math on the time now vs time then needs to execute faster than events happen

If you want it to be so that step never changes as long as the button is held down you need to flip the logic around a bit so that *as long as events keep arriving quickly, the code keeps returning* - for that. You would update the time every time you return and only let the code proceed if more than X time has passed since the last event arrived

Comment: Yeah I forgot about debounce. Thanks for helping me